# Divide list of dates by month SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've got a list of ID's and dates of when they occurred.

```
id|date
1 |2019-01-22
2 |2019-02-13
etc
```

I want to have a table that just lists ID's by month. I have

```
SELECT 
        `a`.`sourceID` AS `Jan 2019`
    FROM
        `all_dates` `a`
    WHERE
        ((MONTH(`a`.`next1`) = 1)
            AND (YEAR(`a`.`next1`) = 2019))
```

As one column, I want 12 columns for each month in 2019. I don't want a union (as far as I can tell). I'm not sure if I'm just putting in the wrong syntax for a subquery or if I need to use a join or what.

```
(SELECT 
        `a`.`sourceID`
    FROM
        `all_dates` `a`
    WHERE
        ((MONTH(`a`.`next1`) = 1)
            AND (YEAR(`a`.`next1`) = 2019))) AS `Jan 2019`,
(SELECT 
        `a`.`sourceID`
    FROM
        `all_dates` `a`
    WHERE
        ((MONTH(`a`.`next1`) = 2)
            AND (YEAR(`a`.`next1`) = 2019))) AS `Feb 2019`
```

I get an error of "subquery returns more than 1 row" with the above. Am I on the right lines and just need to clean it up, or should I be doing something else?

The result I want should look like

```
|jan-2019|feb-2019
| 1      |2
| 4      |3
```

etc.

Comment: What if there are 3 january records, 2 february and 999 december records? What would the output look like?

Comment: @SalmanA If December has 999 records, the december column would have 999 entries and jan and feb would have a bunch of nulls, I guess. Is that the problem?

Comment: Not a problem but i would rather not do it in SQL. The jan column in first row is unrelated to the feb column in that same row. It looks like a report or something.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm setting it up as a view, maybe it would be better to group them somehow. I'd still like to see the report somehow

Answer (score 0):

Following query is an indirect one, also the ouput has null values which does not satisfy the condition , give it a try

```
 SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '01') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `jan_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '02') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `feb_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '03') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `mar_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '04') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `apr_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '05') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `may_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '06') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `jun_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '07') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `jul_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '08') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `aug_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '09') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `sep_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '10') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `oct_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '11') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `nov_2019`,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSTR(`tablename`.`dd`, 6, 2) = '12') THEN `tablename`.`id`
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS `dec_2019`
FROM
    `tablename`;
```

Comment: That kinda works, but I need to remove the null entries. This puts a null whenever the value doesn't match the month given